# function that find uncompleted noted by flags into an array with nested objects

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to build a simple function that return only the uncompleted notes into an array with nested objects.

my object looks like:

```
function uncompletedNotes(notes) {

}

const notes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    description: 'Workout program',
    todos: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Push ups - 10 x 3',
        done: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Abdominals - 20 x 3',
        done: true
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Tapis Roulant - 15min',
        done: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    description: 'Front-end Roadmap',
    todos: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Learn HTML',
        done: true
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Learn CSS',
        done: true
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Learn JavaScript',
        done: true
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Learn Angular',
        done: true
      }
    ]
  }
]

const notesInProgress = uncompletedNotes(notes);
console.log('All notes: ', notes);
console.log('Notes In Progress: ', notesInProgress);
```

i've tried so far with notes.map but i do not know the right way to return only the items with flags  `done: false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for example:

```js
function uncompletedNotes(notes) {
  return notes.reduce((prev, note) => prev.concat(note.todos.filter(td => !td.done)), []);
}

const some_notes = [{
    id: 1,
    description: 'Workout program',
    todos: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Push ups - 10 x 3',
        done: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Abdominals - 20 x 3',
        done: true
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Tapis Roulant - 15min',
        done: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    description: 'Front-end Roadmap',
    todos: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Learn HTML',
        done: true
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Learn CSS',
        done: true
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Learn JavaScript',
        done: true
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Learn Angular',
        done: true
      }
    ]
  }
]

const notesInProgress = uncompletedNotes(some_notes);
console.log('All notes: ', some_notes);
console.log('Notes In Progress: ', notesInProgress);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the notes that contain one or more 'todos' that are flagged as false, you can do this:

```
function uncompletedNotes(notes) {
    return notes.filter((note) =>
        note.todos.some((todo) => todo.done === false)
    )
}
```